# ArcGIS 3.28, clear() except specific graphics

Tags: arcgis-js-api

In ArcGIS 3.28, I need to use `clear()` but exclude some graphics, is there a method to do this? I don't want to remove all the graphics on a layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, ArcGIS JS API provides two way to remove the graphics:

1. `clear()` [click here for more details...](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/graphicslayer-amd.html#clear)
2. `remove(graphic)` [click here for more details...](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/graphicslayer-amd.html#remove)

*In both the cases there is no provision to provide remove condition so I don't think you can directly remove the the feature base on certain condition.*

However still if you need to achieve this below is the same for it-

```
  var graphicsList  = layerObj.graphics;
  for (i = 0; i < graphicsList.length; i++) { 
      if(remove_conditions){
         layerObj.remove(graphicsList[i]);
         i--;
      }
  }
```

***Hoping above sample will help you to achieve the same.***